# Visual Studio 2012 crash when reading a file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I know that this crash was solved in some cases before, but before you call it a duplicate, read this:

- I've tried to reinstall VS2012 Framework.
- I've tried to delete the registry values that suppose to cause this crash.
- I've tried to reinstall VS2012.
- I've tried to disable IntelliTrace.

Now I'll explain what happens.

```
string spath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + "zPosting_" + 0.ToString() + ".post";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(spath);
string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

There are 2 files: zPosting_0.post (17MB), and zPosting_2.post(2MB)

**When I read zPosting_2.post and parse it, it works well.
When I read zPosting_0.post, it crashes when I try to parse the text.**

This is the message:
[image]

I don't know what causes the problem, but I guess it's something with the limit of the buffer size.

I'm using VS2012 on Windows7 32Bit.

How can I prevent this crash without splitting the file? and without reading it line by line?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
here are the first parser lines:

```
string sTerm = "";
List<int> index = new List<int>();
List<int> docs = new List<int>();
int iTF = 0;
int iDF = 0;

int i1, i2;
i1 = 0;
i2 = text.IndexOf("_");
sTerm = text.Substring(0, i2);
```

It crashes sometimes at "int i1, i2;", and sometimes at "i1 = 0".

Comment: Does this not throw any exceptions that can be caught by the debugger? Also, is the file really 17Mb of *text* (and not a binary format)?

Comment: You say it crashes when you go to parse the text, but the code you've given us is just loading it. Are we looking at the right problem?

Comment: Open the event viewer and look up the uncaught exception in the application log

Comment: @ AI G, Yeah, that's what I don't get. Parser works fine, because when I parse other files (with exactly same syntax), it works. Problem isn't in the parser - in fact it crashes somewhere at the "int i1, i2" line, sometimes at "i1 = 0", which I consider safe.

Comment: If you mean it crashes on "sr.ReadToEnd();" - this is READING the file, not PARSING it. Which line is actually throwing the exception? Show us the call stack.

Comment: @Johnbot, I'll just google how can I do it. Never done it before.

Comment: @ShellShock, I added the parser lines, please take a look at it.

Comment: If there's no underscore in `text` then `i2` will be `-1` and `text.Substring(0, i2);` will throw an exception.

Comment: @Johnbot, theres an underscore. Program doesn't even reach that part of code.
here's the beggining of the text of the posting file:
"year_7800_18359_(2,570)(3,286)(3,315)(3,528)(3,992)"

Comment: Again, parser works fine. It can actually parse the file if i cut some part of it and make it smaller. problem happens when the file is 17MB, and it doesn't even throws an exception, it just crashes.

Comment: Here's a [guide on how to use the event log](http://www.cyberlink.com/support/faq-content.do?id=10449)

Comment: Not catching an exception in the code you're writing won't cause Visual Studio to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late, but for anyone else experiencing this problem...

It's most likely that `string text = sr.ReadToEnd();` is causing the crash. Maybe a corrupt file? Regardless, you could try the code below and cycle through to add the lines to your string.

```
string spath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + "zPosting_" + 0.ToString() + ".post";
string text = string.Empty;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(spath))
 {
     while (!sr.EndOfStream)
     {
         text += sr.ReadLine();
     }
 }
```

Alternatively, if `.EndOfStream` is also causing problems, you could try..

```
string spath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + "zPosting_" + 0.ToString() + ".post";
string line, text = string.Empty;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(spath))
 {
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
           text += line; 
      }
 }
```

Hope this helps.